# form will not submit and I have tried all I know

Tags: php, html

My form will not submit. Please help. I have two additional forms that work fine but this one is giving me a lot of trouble. I am not getting any error messages at all. I am fairly new in the php world. It seems simple until I got to this!

Signed A Very frustrated PHP beginner

```
<div class="popSec">
  <div class="pop-outer">
    <div class="pop-inner ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-right">
      <button class="close">x</button>
      <h1>Welcome to !<span>We are glad you want to connect with us!</span></h1>
      <form method="post" action="VisitorForm.php">

        <div class="section">Contact Information
          <div class="inner-wrap ">

            <label>Full Name* 
                <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" style="width:49%; float: left;">
                    <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" style="width:49%;"> </label>
            <label>Telephone Number <input type="number" name="phonenumber" placeholder="Phone Number"></label>
            <label>Email Address* <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address"></label>
            <div class="email-blast">
              <input type="checkbox" name="emailblast">I would like to be added to Hopewell's email list.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="section">Visit Us
          <div class="inner-wrap">
            <label>When do you plan on visiting?<input type="date" name="visitdate" placeholder="Select a date"></label>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="section">Lets Connect!
          <div class="inner-wrap">
            <label>Are you seeking salvation?</label>
            <input type="radio" name="Salvation" value="Yes" align="right">Yes
            <input type="radio" name="Salvation" value="No" align="right">No
            <br><br>
            <label>Have you been baptized?</label>
            <input type="radio" name="Baptism" value="Yes"> Yes
            <input type="radio" name="Baptism" value="No">No
            <br><br>
            <label>Do you want to learn more about being baptized?</label>
            <input type="radio" name="LMBaptism" value="Yes"> Yes
            <input type="radio" name="LMBaptism" value="No">No
            <br><br>
            <label>Are you seeking a church home?</label>
            <input type="radio" name="Church" value="Yes"> Yes
            <input type="radio" name="Church" value="No">No
            <br><br>
            <label>How did you hear about us?</label>
            <select name="Howyouhear">
                        <option value="Person">Family/Friend</option>
                        <option value="Website">Website</option>
                        <option value="Social">Social Media</option>
                        <option value="Flyer">Flyer</option>
                        <option value="Google">Google</option>
                    </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button class="w3-button w3-block w3-section w3-blue w3-ripple w3-padding">SUBMIT</button>

      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

PHP code:

```
<?php 

$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$emailblast =$_POST['emailblast'];
$phone= $_POST['phonenumber'];
$date= $_POST['visitdate'];
$Salvation = $_POST['Salvation'];
$Baptism = $_POST['Baptism'];
$LMBaptism= $_POST['LMBaptism'];
$Church= $_POST['Church'];
$Hear= $_POST['Howyouhear'];

$fullname = $fname . ' ' . $lname ;

$formcontent="Name: $fullname Phone Number: $phone \n Email: 
$email \n Date: $date \n Seeking Sal: $Salvation \n Baptized: $Baptism \n 
Learn More: $LMBaptism \n Church Home: $Church \n How did you hear about us: 
$Hear \n" ;
$recipient = "88888888@gmail.com";
$subject = "Visitor Online Form";

$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");

echo "Thank You!";

?>
```

Comment: It won't submit or the PHP wont process?

Comment: Use the network tab in the developer console to see if it's submitting. Check your server error log for PHP errors.

Comment: I think the php will not process. When I click submit the page stays the same.

Comment: I got this problem couple of weeks ago, In my case some JS prevent submitting my form. So I comment out one by one js file and got the faulty js file. U can follow this process.